# A question about self-intersecting normal crossing divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, chern-classes

Let $D=D_1\cup D_2$ be a simple normal crossing (snc) divisor in a smooth complex projective variety $X$. Let $E=\mathcal{O}_X(V_1)\oplus \mathcal{O}_X(V_2)$. Then, obviousely,
$$
c(E)\equiv 1+c_1(E)+c_2(E)= 1 + PD(D) + PD(D^{(2)})
$$
where $D^{(2)}=D_1\cap D_2$ and PD denotes the Poincare duality. Let $s_1$ and $s_2$ denote the canonical sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(V_1)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(V_2)$. We get a map (of sheaves)
$$
\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus 2}\to \mathcal{O}(E), \quad (f_1,f_2)\to (f_1s_1,f_2s_2)
$$
Since the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{D_1}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{D_2}$ (this sheaf is supported on $D$) is the cokernel of the dual map.
$$
\mathcal{O}(E)^* \to (\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus 2})^*\cong \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus 2}
$$
we also get
$$
c(\mathcal{O}_{D_1}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{D_2})=1 + PD(D) + PD(D^{(2)}).
$$
Now suppose $D\subset X$ is a self-intersecting normal crossing divisor that is the image of an immersion $\iota \colon \widetilde{D}\to X$ with the complex condimension $2$ self-intersection locus $D^{(2)}$(in the snc case $\widetilde{D}$ is the disjiont union of $D_1$ and $D_2$). The anolgue of $\mathcal{O}_{D_1}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{D_2}$ can still be defined in this case: it is the direct image (push-forward) sheaf $\iota_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{D}}$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{D}}$ via $\iota$.

How can we show that (even over rational numbers)
$$
c(\iota_* \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{D}})=1 + PD(D) + PD(D^{(2)})?
$$
The issue is that an analog of $E$ is no longer defined (or I don't know how to define anything like it without using orbifold vector bundles).

Comment: I don't want to use a blowup to make $D$ snc.

Comment: You can use Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch.

Comment: The proof of GRR for immersions (see Corollary 5.22) in  https://www.math.harvard.edu/media/patrick.pdf uses blowup to reduce to embeddings and snc divisors. I think if you want to use GRR, you will end up using blowup to make the calculation.